# How to use several property-placeholder in different contexts

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, properties-file

I use Spring Framework and Spring Security. There are different places where I need to use the page path. For example, "/mainpath".
I place it in /WEB-INF/classes/path.properties.
The path should be used in servlet-context.xml and in security-context.xml.
If the following is placed in both contexts

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/classes/path.properties"/>
```

it will result in

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "Could not resolve placeholder 'main.page' in string value "${main.page}"
```

The following does not give required result.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/classes/path.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

UPD.
path.properties:

```
main.page=mainpage
```

I exclude property-placeholder from servlet-context.xml. The error still arises.
The part of security-context:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/path.properties" 
    ignore-unresolvable="false"/>
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/${main.page}" access="isAuthenticated()" 
    requires-channel="http"/>
...
</http>
```

I tried to place path.properties in different folders.
Property-placeholder is also used in datasource-tx-jpa.xml with other property file.

Folders structure:

[image: Folders structure]

Stacktrace:

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'main.page' in string value "/${main.page}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'main.page' in string value "/${main.page}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:211)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:180)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'main.page' in string value "/${main.page}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:194)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:158)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitIndexedArgumentValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitMap(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:259)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitIndexedArgumentValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:208)
    ... 18 more
```

UPD 2.
The problem is in property-placeholder placed in datasource-tx-jpa.xml, which is imported in root-context.xml before security-context.xml. So it can't find placeholder in property file associated with datasource-tx-jpa.xml.
The attribute "ignore-unresolvable" of property-placeholder should be set to true in the first imported context.

Comment: There is a serious difference between the subject of your question and the content.

Are you sure your property file contains main.page as a key? Could you please post it as a part of your question, next to the exact stacktrace?

Comment: @KurtDuBois you are right. The subject and content are not the same, so I've renamed the question. I've also found decision.

Comment: don't forget that you shouldn't try having 2 different context:property-placeholder tags loaded. even if in different subcontexts

Comment: @MarianP In that case how to use properties in different subcontext?

Comment: you can only load them once, so it needs to be in one place

Answer (score 1):

Define your file location as an `classpath`, ***classes*** not seem a good name, if you use maven put your file under resource folder, and write your property-placeholder as

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/path.properties" />
```

If you are not use maven define the folder at your configuration it is classes(i recommend rename it) in your configuration, define this folder `Build Path->Configure Build Path->Source Add` classes folder at this tab

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in property-placeholder placed in datasource-tx-jpa.xml, which is imported in root-context.xml before security-context.xml. So it can't find placeholder in property file associated with datasource-tx-jpa.xml. The attribute "ignore-unresolvable" of property-placeholder should be set to true in the first imported context.